# Flutter:Inconsistently getting error: The getter 'ioRequest' isn't defined for the class 'IOClient'

Tags: flutter

This problem appeared to me after implementing a search to the database, previously I had no problem, it worked well for me, but from one moment to another this problem appeared and I do not understand the problem.

/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/io_client.dart:31:9: Error: Expected an identifier, but got '..'. ..followRedirects = request.followRedirects

/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/io_client.dart:36:9: Error: The getter 'ioRequest' isn't defined for the class 'IOClient'. - 'IOClient' is from 'package:http/src/io_client.dart'

('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/io_client.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'ioRequest'.
var response = await stream.pipe(ioRequest) as HttpClientResponse;
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 904

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

```
String mensaje = "";
  String urldata="https://example/api/data.php";
  Future<List> cargarCitas(String usuarioId, String mascotaId) async {    
    var usuario = usuarioId;
    var mascota =mascotaId;
    var preguntaData = "4";
    final respuestacitas = await http.post(Uri.encodeFull(urldata), headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }, body: {
      "usuario": usuario,    
      "pregunta": preguntaData,
      "mascota": mascota,
    });
    
    if (respuestacitas.statusCode == 200) {
      final cargarDayaReserva = jsonDecode(respuestacitas.body) as List;
      reservaMascota = cargarDayaReserva.map((e) => ReservaData.fromJson(e)).toList();
      return reservaMascota;
    } else {
      setState(() {
        mensaje = "cannot connect to the database";
      });
    }
  }
```

please can someone help me with this matter. I have already tried to create the project again and nothing, I have tried to uninstall some packages and nothing remains the same.